# Labelling my arrows

Tags: labels

```
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,column sep=1cm,row sep=0.5cm]{
  0 & E(K)[m] & E(K) & E(K) \\
& H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E[m]) & H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E(\bar{K}) & H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E(\bar{K})) \\
};
 \draw[->,font=\scriptsize,every node/.style={above},rounded corners]
(m-1-1) edge (m-1-2) 
(m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
(m-1-3) edge["$m$"] (m-1-4)
(m-1-4.east) --+(5pt,0)|-+(0,-7.5pt)-|([xshift=-5pt]m-2-2.west)--(m-2-2.west)
(m-2-2) edge (m-2-3)
(m-2-3) edge["$m$"] (m-2-4)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

Oddly enough, I'm not able to put $[m]$ as my labels instead of just $m$. Other types of brackets seem to work though. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra pair of braces to hide the inner square brackets:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,quotes}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,column sep=1cm,row sep=0.5cm]{
  0 & E(K)[m] & E(K) & E(K) \\
& H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E[m]) & H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E(\bar{K}) & H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E(\bar{K})) \\
};
 \draw[->,font=\scriptsize,every node/.style={above},rounded corners]
(m-1-1) edge (m-1-2) 
(m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
(m-1-3) edge["{$[m]$}"] (m-1-4)
(m-1-4.east) --+(5pt,0)|-+(0,-7.5pt)-|([xshift=-5pt]m-2-2.west)--(m-2-2.west)
(m-2-2) edge (m-2-3)
(m-2-3) edge["{$[m]$}"] (m-2-4)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course that's the first thing I tried, but it doesn't work. Any reason?

Comment: @HaikalYeo Please see my answer and the image attached. It works. Are you not getting the same result with my code?

Comment: Nope. TexShop refuses to compile... :/